# OptionTransferSelect issue in Struts2

Tags: struts2

the optiontransferselect in the JSP is not populating the doubleList values. though the value is printed on the JSP as an iiterator .

the double list is a List `<Editor>` .

```
 <pre><s:optiontransferselect 
         headerKey="-1"
         headerValue="---Please Select---"
         doubleHeaderKey="-1"
         doubleHeaderValue="---Please Select---"
         leftTitle="Availabl"
         rightTitle="Selecte"
         theme="simple"
         name="availableScript"
         id="availableScriptId"
         list="availableScriptList" 
         listKey="id"
         listValue="name"
         size="10"
         doubleSize="10"
         doubleName="selectedScript"
         doubleId="selectedScriptId"
         doubleList="selectedScriptList"
         doubleListKey="id"
         doubleListValue="%{name}"
         allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
         allowUpDownOnRight="false"
         allowSelectAll="false"
         allowAddAllToLeft="false"
         allowAddAllToRight="false"

        /></pre>
```

Not sure what the issue is .I am using struts2.0.11

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

```
<s:head/>
```

in the head of the JSP page for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody knows how to activate **auto sort** option for optiontransferselect?

I've found that when you click in *trasnfer item between list* button this javascript function is onvoked:

```
function moveSelectedOptions(objSourceElement, objTargetElement, toSort, notMove1, notMove2) {...}
```

This function is located in file **optiontransferselect.js** who belongs to struts javascript library. By default, argument *toSort* is *FALSE* and **s:optiontransferselect** component doesn't have an attribute to set this value as *TRUE*.

Maybe I should change this .js file for my own file. What do you think?

Thanks!